# Add a table to existing PDF itextsharp with pdfStamper and VB or C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, itext

I want to use a function to insert a table to a existing PDF like:

```
Private Shared Function wTable(ByVal cols As Integer) As iTextSharp.text.Table
        Dim table As New iTextSharp.text.Table(cols)
        With table
            .WidthPercentage = 100
            .BorderWidth = 0
            .Cellpadding = 1
            .Cellspacing = 0
            .TableFitsPage = False
            .CellsFitPage = True
            .AutoFillEmptyCells = True
            .Widths = New Single() {20, 80}
        End With
        Dim font As iTextSharp.text.Font = font8
        Dim fontBold As iTextSharp.text.Font = font8Bold
        Dim c As Cell = New Cell(New Phrase("Allacci Sparsi", fontBold))
        c.SetHorizontalAlignment("center")
        table.AddCell(c, 0, 0)
        Dim str As String = "Il termine di esecuzione dei lavori è stabilito all’art. 14 del Foglio Condizioni e di seguito definiti in Tabella 1. " _
                            & "All'art. 16 del 'Foglio Condizioni' sono definiti i riferimenti per l’applicazione delle penali in caso di ritardo nell’esecuzione delle opere richieste. " _
                                & " All'art. 17 del 'Foglio Condizioni' sono definiti i criteri per l’incentivo sulla celerità di intervento."
        c = New Cell(New Phrase(str, font))
        c.SetHorizontalAlignment("left")
        table.AddCell(c, 0, 1)
        Return table
    End Function
```

then call it using stamper like:

```
Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing
Dim stamper As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper = Nothing
Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = Nothing
Dim rect As iTextSharp.text.Rectangle = Nothing
Dim pageCount As Integer = 0
Try
    reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(sourcePdf)
    rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)
    stamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, New System.IO.FileStream(outputPdf, IO.FileMode.Create))
    cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1)
    Dim ct = New ColumnText(cb)
    ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 36, PageSize.A4.Width - 36, PageSize.A4.Height - 300)
    ct.AddElement(wTable(2))
    ct.Go()
    stamper.Close()
    reader.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
```

However program throws exepction saying: **"Element is not allowed"**.

I have seen an example inserting table, but they do not use pdfstamper [here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1365-create-custom-table-pdf-document-using-itextsharp.aspx) they use

```
  doc.Open()
...
    doc.Add(table)
...
    doc.Close()
```

How to add a table using pdfstamper with itextsharp, in C# or even in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dim oldFile As String = "D:\karuppasamy\OBM Application Form 2014 Final.pdf"

    Dim newFile As String = "D:\karuppasamy\PDF\OBM Application Form 2014 Final.pdf"

    Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing

    Dim stamper As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper = Nothing

    Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = Nothing

    Dim rect As iTextSharp.text.Rectangle = Nothing

    Dim pageCount As Integer = 0

    Try
        reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(oldFile)

        rect = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1)

        stamper = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, New System.IO.FileStream(newFile, IO.FileMode.Create))

        cb = stamper.GetOverContent(1)
        Dim ct = New ColumnText(cb)
        ct.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        ct.SetSimpleColumn(70, 36, PageSize.A4.Width - 36, PageSize.A4.Height - 300)
        Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(2)
        'create column sizes 
        Dim rows As Single() = {135.0F, 145.0F}
        'set row width 
        nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows)

        nTbl.AddCell(New Paragraph("Application Ref No:", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15)))
        nTbl.AddCell(New Paragraph("HPOBM00017", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 15)))

        'coords x=300,y=300
        '  nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, 50, 40, 835, stamper.GetOverContent(1))
        nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, 20, 300, 835, stamper.GetOverContent(1))

        stamper.Close()
        reader.Close()
        ct.Go()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

Comment: Would be better to include a high level description of your changes. Also, your code has hardcoded paths to your home directory which limits portability.

Comment: you should explain your answer not just posting a code

Answer (score 1):

Just insert something like before `stamper.Close()`:

```
    Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(2)
    'create column sizes 
    Dim rows As Single() = {50.0F, 250.0F}
    'set row width 
    nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows)
    nTbl.AddCell("Cell1")
    nTbl.AddCell("Cell2")
    'coords x=300,y=300
    nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, 50, 300, 300, stamper.GetOverContent(1))


    stamper.Close()
    reader.Close()
```